# Is it possible to collect from data in excel or CSV file using HTML5 Local database only, without using Mysql?

Tags: php, database, html, xhtml, local-storage

**It's a example:**

I have a HTML form on a webpage

[image]

I want to collect all data of form ( Data, which user will submit) in Excel or CSV sheet.?

[image]

Is it possible with HTML 5 only? or will be required Mysql, php, apache etc?

Browser I will use is : Google Chrome , no other browser need to consider

Application will run on local PC. if it's not possible with HTML5 local database, I will install portable XAMPP.

**Any demo , example would be appreciated?**

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage is a key/value store, and there's not really any way to change the way Chrome decides to save that data in order to get it to write it to a CSV file instead.

Comment: Sorry I mean from HTML5 Local Database.

Comment: Assuming you mean the section of HTML5 called "Web SQL Database", this has been more-or-less abandoned (see http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) - and the answer would still be the same...that specification uses SQLite as the database, there's no facility for changing that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using an html5 web sql database rather than local storage, since you're dealing with tabular data.

[HTML 5 Web SQL Database article](http://openbit.co.uk/?p=135)

[HTML 5 Databases demo](http://html5demos.com/database)